# React Material UI Dialog form data state not set correctly when updated

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, material-ui, dialog

When selecting new data for the dialog form it will incorrectly display the original data. Only after closing the dialog and then reopening the same one, attempted before, does the form display the correct values. I believe there is some `useEffect` and `useState` shenanigans but not sure how to resolve.

To Test click Button `Data 1` to verify data is correct and then click `Data 2`. It will show the data corresponding to `Data1` not `Data 2` where we obviously want to see the `Data 2` values.

In the demo, and actual implementation, the selectedId state is needed because it is refernce elsewhere.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-mountain-8n9n9r?file=/Demo.tsx)

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
import SomeDialog from "./SomeDialog";
import { FormData } from "./FormData";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";

let initialFormData: FormData[] = [
  { name: "data1", id: 0, location: "here" },
  { name: "data2", id: 1, location: "there" }
];

function Demo(): any {
  const [selectedData, setSelectedData] = useState<FormData>(
    initialFormData[0]
  );

  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState<number>(0);

  const [dialogOpen, setDialogOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const handleDialogOpen = useCallback(() => setDialogOpen(true), []);
  const handleDialogClose = useCallback(() => setDialogOpen(false), []);

  const onClick = (index: number) => {
    setSelectedId(index);
    handleDialogOpen();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let data = initialFormData.find((data) => data.id === selectedId);

    setSelectedData(data);
  }, [selectedId]);

  return (
    <div style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100vw" }}>
      <Button
        onClick={() => {
          onClick(0);
        }}
      >
        Data 1
      </Button>

      <Button
        onClick={() => {
          onClick(1);
        }}
      >
        Data 2
      </Button>

      <SomeDialog
        open={dialogOpen}
        onClose={handleDialogClose}
        data={selectedData}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Demo;
```

Dialog Form

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, ChangeEvent } from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { Button, Dialog, Box } from "@mui/material";

import { FormData } from "./FormData";

interface SomeDialogProps {
  open: boolean;
  onClose: () => void;
  data: FormData;
}

function SomeDialog(props: SomeDialogProps) {
  const { open, onClose, data } = props;

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState<FormData>(data);

  useEffect(() => {
    setFormData(data);
  }, [data]);

  function handleDataInputChange(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    const { id, value } = event.target;
    setFormData({ ...formData, [id]: value });
  }

  function handleSubmit(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.info(formData);

    onClose();
  }

  return (
    <Dialog
      open={open}
      onClose={onClose}
      aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
      aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
    >
      <Box
        component="form"
        sx={{
          "& .MuiTextField-root": { m: 1, width: "25ch" }
        }}
        noValidate
        autoComplete="off"
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      >
        <TextField
          id="id"
          label="Id"
          defaultValue={formData.id}
          onChange={handleDataInputChange}
        />

        <TextField
          id="name"
          label="Name"
          defaultValue={formData.name}
          onChange={handleDataInputChange}
        />

        <TextField
          id="location"
          label="Location"
          defaultValue={formData.location}
          onChange={handleDataInputChange}
        />

        <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
      </Box>
    </Dialog>
  );
}

export default SomeDialog;
```

```
export interface FormData {
  name: string;
  id: number;
  location: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems here:

### Demo.tsx

In your `Demo.tsx` file, `setSelectedData(data)` call in the `useEffect` is asynchronous. It means that when you call `handleDialogOpen()` immediately after setting `selectedId`, the `selectedData` state may not have been updated yet, leading to the dialog displaying the old data. Instead, you can combine the logic of both `selectedId` and `selectedData` in the same function before calling `handleDialogOpen()` like this:

```
const onClick = (index: number) => {
  let data = initialFormData.find((data) => data.id === index);
  setSelectedData(data);
  setSelectedId(index);
  handleDialogOpen();
};
```

This ensures that when you open the dialog, `selectedData` is updated with the correct data immediately before opening the dialog.

### SomeDialog.tsx

Similarly, in your `SomeDialog.tsx` file, `formData` is set to the value of `data` prop on the first render. However, as aforementioned, React state updates are asynchronous, which means that when the `data` prop changes, the `formData` state variable is not updated immediately during the render cycle.

So, if the `data` prop changes (for example, when you open the dialog with different data), `formData` will still hold the previous value from the previous render. This is because the state update caused by changing the `data` prop hasn't had the chance to take effect yet.

To fix this issue, you should directly use the `data` prop to initialize the form fields, and you can remove the local `formData` state entirely:

```
import React, { useEffect, ChangeEvent } from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { Button, Dialog, Box } from "@mui/material";

import { FormData } from "./FormData";

interface SomeDialogProps {
  open: boolean;
  onClose: () => void;
  data: FormData;
}

function SomeDialog(props: SomeDialogProps) {
  const { open, onClose, data } = props;

  function handleDataInputChange(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    const { id, value } = event.target;
    // No need to update local state, directly use data prop
    data[id] = value;
  }

  function handleSubmit(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.info(data);

    onClose();
  }

  return (
    <Dialog
      open={open}
      onClose={onClose}
      aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
      aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
    >
      <Box
        component="form"
        sx={{
          "& .MuiTextField-root": { m: 1, width: "25ch" }
        }}
        noValidate
        autoComplete="off"
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      >
        <TextField
          id="id"
          label="Id"
          defaultValue={data.id}
          onChange={handleDataInputChange}
        />

        <TextField
          id="name"
          label="Name"
          defaultValue={data.name}
          onChange={handleDataInputChange}
        />

        <TextField
          id="location"
          label="Location"
          defaultValue={data.location}
          onChange={handleDataInputChange}
        />

        <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
      </Box>
    </Dialog>
  );
}

export default SomeDialog;
```

Comment: @JackHickson Happy to help! If this answer solves your issue, please mark it as accepted.